# Automatic "for" and "id"

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

Because we cannot assume our components are singletons: I am trying to automatically handle giving `htmlFor` to a label and field. We see below I use `useMemo` and lodash `uniqueId` to memoize a unique id for the form on initial render. I had to give `useMemo` and empty array as second argument so it never re-calculates the id. Is there some automated way to handle this in `final-form`?

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form';
import { uniqueId } from 'lodash';

function TaskForm() {

    const id = useMemo(() => uniqueId('_form'), []);
    const getFor = name => name + id;

    return (
        <>
            <h3>Create a task</h3>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                {({ handleSubmit, pristine, invalid, ...rest }) => {(
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor={getFor('firstName')}>First Name</label>
                            <Field name="firstName" id={getFor('firstName')} component="input" placeholder="First Name" />
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || invalid}>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                )}}
            </Form>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: This code rocks!!!!  Thanks for showing it.  You don't need getFor function.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike for thinking so much trying with me! I know MDN docs say we can wrap the input component within the `<label>` however the bootstrap4 styling needed the label separate so it led me to this. Thanks very much again for thinking code with me!